# Polyurethane tube simulation in Solidworks

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-analysis, finite-element-method

I am doing polyurethane tube simulation in Solidworks Simulation. I am using material PUR for polyurethane already defined in Solidworks. I have a question about the model type to be selected for material? As polyurethane is plastic, should I choose Non-Linear elastic or plastic or hyperelastic? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This depends on the simulation scenario in question - what sort of deformation are you expecting? Lightly squishing a seal is very different to completely crushing a tube... Please provide more details, preferably including screenshots/diagrams. Do you have the non-linear (SolidWorks 'Premium', I think) simulation package?

Comment: Just to provide more information, I have done the uniaxial tensile test using Instran instrument in the lab and generated the stress-strain plot. I want to do this simulation to get to the best settings in Solidworks which generate result that matches with lab test result. Also, the real application of my PUR tube is different than just tension force. Yes, I do have SolidWorks ' Premium' Package..

Comment: @JonathanRSwift

Comment: @RLil: it would be better to include the additional information in your comment as an edit in your question.

Comment: You can easily see whether the tensile test results were linear or nonlinear. If they were linear the stress-strain plot is a straight line, if they were nonlinear it is not straight!